# Enabling the 16 lane PCIe slot on the Lenovo ThinkCentre Edge 71

Tags: bios, pci-express, thinkcentre

The [Lenovo ThinkCentre Edge 71, type 1578](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/desktops-and-all-in-ones/thinkcentre-edge-desktops/thinkcentre-edge-71/1578), has two single-lane PCI Express slots and one sixteen-lane PCI Express slot.  Devices inserted into the ×1 slots (for example, NVMe adapters) work fine.  However, devices (even the same devices) inserted into the ×16 slot power on but are not seen by the operating system.  What's the problem, here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit <kbd>F1</kbd> during boot to get to the BIOS settings, then choose `Devices` → `Video Setup`, and set `Multi-Monitor Support` to `Enabled`.

Presumably whoever designed this interface couldn't imagine the PCIe×16 slot being used for anything other than a graphics card.

Comment: *whoever designed this interface couldn't imagine the PCIe×16 slot being used for anything other than a graphics card* This pretty much sums up the reasoning of any manufacturer.